# MPI C++ Runtime Error: signal 11 (Segmentation fault) with multi-dimensional array creation

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, mpi

## Making Mandelbrot with MPI

So I've made a Mandelbrot generator and everything worked fine. Now I'm throwing in a speedup from MPI. Process 0 generates a file name `mbrot.ppm` and adds the appropriate metadata, then divides up the workload into chunks.

Each process receives the chunk's starting and ending positions and gets to work calculating its portion of the Mandelbrot set. To write to the `mbrot.ppm` file, each process saves its data in an array so it doesn't write to the file before the previous process finishes.

### My Problem

Its a runtime error that says:

```
Primary job terminated normally, but 1 process returned
a non-zero exit code. Per user-direction, the job has been aborted.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 0 on node Lenovo exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

I believe it comes from the line `int data[3][xrange][yrange];` (line 120) since the print statement after this line never executes. Would there be an obvious reason I'm missing why this multi-dimensional array is causing me problems?

### Full Code

```
#include <iostream>

#include <mpi.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>

#include <fstream>

#define MCW MPI_COMM_WORLD

using namespace std;

struct Complex {
  double r;
  double i;
};

Complex operator + (Complex s, Complex t) {
  Complex v;
  v.r = s.r + t.r;
  v.i = s.i + t.i;
  return v;
};

Complex operator * (Complex s, Complex t) {
  Complex v;
  v.r = s.r * t.r - s.i * t.i;
  v.i = s.r * t.i + s.i * t.r;
  return v;
};

int rcolor(int iters) {
  if (iters == 255) return 0;
  return 32 * (iters % 8);
};

int gcolor(int iters) {
  if (iters == 255) return 0;
  return 32 * (iters % 8);
};

int bcolor(int iters) {
  if (iters == 255) return 0;
  return 32 * (iters % 8);
};

int mbrot(Complex c, int maxIters) {

  int i = 0;
  Complex z;
  z = c;
  while (i < maxIters && z.r * z.r + z.i * z.i < 4) {
    z = z * z + c;
    i++;
  }
  return i;

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  int rank, size;

  MPI_Init( & argc, & argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MCW, & rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MCW, & size);

  if (size < 2) {
    printf("Not an MPI process if only 1 process runs.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (size % 2 != 0) {
    printf("Please use a even number\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  Complex c1, c2, c;
  char path[] = "brot.ppm";
  int DIM;
  int chunk[4];
  c1.r = -1;
  c1.i = -1;
  c2.r = 1;
  c2.i = 1;

  if (rank == 0) { //start the file
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(path);
    DIM = 2000; // pixel dimensions
    fout << "P3" << endl; // The file type .ppm
    fout << DIM << " " << DIM << endl; // dimensions of the image
    fout << "255" << endl; // color depth
    fout.close();

    // making dimesions marks
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      chunk[0] = 0; // startX
      chunk[1] = DIM; // endX
      chunk[2] = (DIM / size) * i; // startY
      chunk[3] = (DIM / size) * (i + 1); // endY

      MPI_Send(chunk, 4, MPI_INT, i, 0, MCW);
    };

  };

  MPI_Recv(chunk, 4, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MCW, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

  printf("Process %d recieved chunk\n\t StartX: %d, EndX: %d\n\t StartY: %d, EndY: %d\n", rank, chunk[0], chunk[1], chunk[2], chunk[3]);

  // do stuff save in array
  // data[3 elements][Xs][Ys]
  int xrange = chunk[1] - chunk[0];
  int yrange = chunk[3] - chunk[2];
  printf("Process %d, x: %d, y: %d\n", rank, xrange, yrange);
  int data[3][xrange][yrange];
  printf("done\n");

  // generate data for mandlebrot
  for (int j = chunk[2]; j < chunk[3]; ++j) {
    for (int i = chunk[0]; i < chunk[1]; ++i) {
      // calculate one pixel of the DIM x DIM image
      c.r = (i * (c1.r - c2.r) / DIM) + c2.r;
      c.i = (j * (c1.i - c2.i) / DIM) + c2.i;
      int iters = mbrot(c, 255);
      data[0][i][j] = rcolor(iters);
      data[1][i][j] = gcolor(iters);
      data[2][i][j] = bcolor(iters);
    }
  }
  printf("here2\n");

  // taking turns to write their data to file
  for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
    if (rank == k) {
      ofstream fout;
      fout.open(path, ios::app);
      fout << rank << " was here" << endl;

      for (int j = chunk[2]; j < chunk[3]; ++j) {
        for (int i = chunk[0]; i < chunk[1]; ++i) {
          fout << data[0][i][j] << " " << data[1][i][j] << " " << data[2][i][j] << " ";
        }
        fout << endl;
      }
      printf("Process %d done and waiting\n", rank);
    } else {
      MPI_Barrier(MCW);
    }
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
};
```

#### How to Run

```
$ mpic++ -o mbrot.out mbrot.cpp
$ mpirun -np 4 mbrot.out
```

Comment: you might be trying to allocators too much data on the stack. try `ulimit -s unlimited` before invoking `mpirun`. or dynamically allocate `data` with `new`.

Comment: Standard C++ does not have variable-length arrays (such as `int data[3][xrange][yrange];` in your code).

Comment: Which version of the C++ standard are you referring to? In my understanding, support started at C++14.

Comment: fwiw, `typedef myarray [3][xrange][yrange]; myarray& data = *(reinterpret_cast<myarray *>(new int[3*xrange*yrange]);` does the trick with `g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet VLAs (variable-length arrays) are standard in C language (since C99), but not supported in any C++ standard, not even in the upcoming C++20. GNU compiler supports them in C++ as a non-standard language extension.

Comment: My mpirun version is Open MPI 4.0.3.

Comment: Is it considered a 'variable-length array' because the program doesn't know the size of the array until runtime? So c++ doesn't have multi-dimensional, variable-length arrays?